# How to convert this script to an Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, coalesce, isnull

I have to create a script that would be executed both in SQL Server and Oracle databases. The script is:

```
update my_view
set value = 'Approved'
where token_name = 'TOKEN_NAME'
and isnull(value,'') = '
```

I have never run a script in Oracle but I know from the internet that Oracle doesn't have isnull(it is NVL) or empty string.

Is there any way I can create just one script for both(like using COALESCE- which I don't really know how to use)?If not what would be the equivalent script in Oracle?

Comment: What is a "sql database" as distinct from Oracle?

Comment: SQL Server database

Comment: I don't know SQL Server, and I can't tell what the last condition is meant to be. (Is that really a SINGLE single-quote after the equal sign at the end? Is that a typo? If not what does it mean?) In any case, if you can explain it in plain English, such as `value must be either the empty string or .....`, I may be able to help. The solution shouldn't use non-SQL Standard functions; best to use `coalesce`, or a `case` expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard way to write the logic is:

```
update my_view
    set value = 'Approved'
    where token_name = 'TOKEN_NAME' and
          (value is null or value = '');
```

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.

On the other hand, updating views is not necessarily supported in all databases.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . The OP is looking for logic that works in both Oracle and SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, empty strings don't exist in Oracle.  They can be handled in a few ways.  `Coalesce()`, and `NVL()` operate similar to `isnull()`.  Out of the 3, Coalesce is the standard.  From Oracle docs:

```
COALESCE (expr1, expr2) = CASE WHEN expr1 IS NOT NULL THEN expr1 ELSE expr2 END
```

Alternatively you can do this:

```
UPDATE my_view
SET value = 'Approved'
WHERE token_name = 'TOKEN_NAME'
AND nullif(value,'') IS NULL
```

`nullif()` will evaluate an empty string to null (which it already should be in Oracle).